# how to fix: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'returnReasonRepository' parameter 0;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run the spring boot application but I got the below error:

Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'returnReasonRepository' defined in class path resource [muscat/configuration/RepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'returnReasonRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springReturnReasonRepository' defined in muscat.repository.SpringReturnReasonRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ServiceApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional .muscat.repository.SpringReturnReasonRepository.findByCode(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional .muscat.repository.SpringReturnReasonRepository.findByCode(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type ReturnReason!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional .muscat.repository.SpringReturnReasonRepository.findByCode(java.lang.String)! No property code found for type ReturnReason!

this is the entity:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

    @Entity
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
    public class ReturnReason {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column
        private String reasonCode;
    
        @Column
        private String reasonDescription;
    
    
        @Column
        private String reasonType;
    }


and this is the 

        public interface ReturnReasonRepository extends MessageRepository<ReturnReason> {
            Optional<ReturnReason> findByCode(String reasonCode);
        }
        
        
        public class ReturnReasonRepositoryImpl implements ReturnReasonRepository {
            private final SpringReturnReasonRepository springReturnReasonRepository;
        
            public ReturnReasonRepositoryImpl(SpringReturnReasonRepository springReturnReasonRepository) {
                this.springReturnReasonRepository = springReturnReasonRepository;
            }
        
        
            @Override
            public Optional<ReturnReason> findByCode(String reasonCode) {
                return springReturnReasonRepository.findByCode(reasonCode);
            }
        
            @Override
            public ReturnReason save(ReturnReason returnReason) {
                return springReturnReasonRepository.save(returnReason);
            }
    
    
        public interface SpringReturnReasonRepository extends CrudRepository<ReturnReason, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ReturnReason> {
            Optional<ReturnReason> findByCode(String reasonCode);
        }
    
    
    @Configuration
    public class RepositoryConfiguration {
    
    
        @Bean
        public BankInformationRepository bankInformationRepository(SpringBankInformationRepository springBankInformationRepository) {
            return new BankInformationRepositoryImpl(springBankInformationRepository);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ReturnReasonRepository returnReasonRepository(SpringReturnReasonRepository springReturnReasonRepository) {
            return new ReturnReasonRepositoryImpl(springReturnReasonRepository);
        }
    }
```

what is my mistake and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> muscat.repository.SpringReturnReasonRepository.findByCode(java.lang.String)!
> No property code found for type ReturnReason!

This is your error. In `SpringReturnReasonRepository`, you have `findByCode` but there is no property named `code` in your `ReturnReason` entity. If you rename this method to `findByReasonCode`, it will work.

If you want to know more about JPA repository method naming convention, you can refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries) link.